# Vertically align image with single line of text

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a list of different country flags, and below them I wish to have the name of the country. Of course listing the flags is no problem but my issue is aligning the correct icon directly above the name of the country. What is the best method of going about this, would it be a mixture of CSS and tables?

The idea would be:

---

FLAG ICON

Albania

---

Browser resizing is also an issue as I'd like them to stay put so that it doesn't screw up at different screen sizes/resolutions

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried, and what problems have you encountered? Your question isn't specific enough.

Comment: So far the only thing I have tried is a row of icons then attempting to space the country names evenly below them, because they are not linked they do not stay together though when the browser is resized. I'm sure it can be done with tables just not sure how

Comment: There are a million ways to lay out images with text but I'd suggest having a look at the figure and figcaption tags.

Comment: you can either put them in a span: `<li><span class="flag brazil"></span><li>` or you can use `li:before` and set them as background-images

Comment: I did try using <li> tag with span but couldnt get it going, do you know where I could see a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest putting each flag with it's country name in separate floated divs.

```
<div>
<img src="flag.jpg"/>
UK
</div>

<div>
<img src="flag.jpg"/>
USA
</div>
```

Comment: I did think of that however I have a large number of flags to do and I believe it would become pretty hard to manage with such large numbers

Comment: Something like this is the right approach. You'll need to use a script or something to manage your volume for you.

Comment: If you have a large number of countries, if would be usefull to store them in a php array. Then all you need to do is run a loop to display them.

Comment: Is there any way I could see a demo of it? Sorry to be a pain I'm just still stumped on how to do it with a div

Comment: Any kind of block container will do. Could be a div, li, even a link if you're working in html5.

Comment: It worked after a bit of tweaking! Using div with display:inline-block;

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using flag as a background for element. It's nice and clean:

Here's demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zXBfL

HTML:

```
<div class="countryList">
    <div class="country" style="background-image: url(http://www.virtualglobaltaskforce.com/wp-content/themes/VGT/images/flag_uk.gif)">United Kingdom</div>
    <div class="country" style="background-image: url(http://www.virtualglobaltaskforce.com/wp-content/themes/VGT/images/flag_uk.gif)">Portugal</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.countryList .country {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 80px 10px 10px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-position: center 20px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 120px;
    text-align:center;
}
```